# Deploying MongoDB, CouchDb on OpenVZ?

Tags: linux, deployment, mongodb, couchdb

I want to write hobbistic app and deploy it on Linux 64 bit on OpenVZ. I googled and it seems that MongoDB doesn't work well under OpenVZ environment so the way to go is CouchDB? Or for small databases on just one server without any extraordinary featues I can go with MongoDB?
Best regards
Artur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a brand new application, the database and OpenVZ will probably not matter much. I suggest choosing the one you are most familiar with (including SQL databases) so that you can focus on the application features.

On the other hand, if you want to learn a database, then choose the one you want to learn, and don't worry about performance yet. For example, see this question of [comparing various NoSQL databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720508/redis-couchdb-or-cassandra).

Answer (score 0):

If later you want to replicate your data with couchDB, keep in your mind that couchDB doesn't support persistence replication !